# How this code works to replace the values in previous lines in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am learning Pandas, and I encountered a problem in my textbook which is hard for me to understand, my code is below:

```
amzn=pd.read_csv('data/amzn_stock.csv',index_col='Date',parse_dates=['Date'])
amzn_close=amzn['Close']
amzn_daily_return=amzn_close.pct_change()
amzn_daily_return=amzn_daily_return.dropna()
mean=amzn_daily_return.mean()
std=amzn_daily_return.std()
abs_z_score=amzn_daily_return.sub(mean).abs().div(std)

pcts=[abs_z_score.lt(i).mean() for i in range (1,4)] #lt=less
print('{:.3f} fall within 1 standard deviation.'
     '{:.3f} within 2 and {:.3f} within 3'.format(*pcts))
```

I am ok for all of the statement except the last line:

```
print('{:.3f} fall within 1 standard deviation.'
         '{:.3f} within 2 and {:.3f} within 3'.format(*pcts))
```

I know it tries to use the values in pcts to replace {:.3f}, but I don't really know how this works. From my experience, I know for example in the following code:

```
print('%s. capital of %s?\n'%(1, 'New York'))
```

%s will be replaced by 1, and second %s will be replaced by New York.

So how does my previous example work? Is there any reference I can read online?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know what pcts is? Do you know what * does? Do you know what {:.3f} stands for? Do you know the syntax for .format?

Comment: I only know how pcts come out, it is list comprehension.

Comment: "Any reference"? But of course! The official documentation is online, and it comes with a tutorial, which, amongst other stuff you may want to learn, [fully explains `.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method).

Comment: this link is very useful

Comment: another useful link for you: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists